# Populate DropDownList options based on the other DropDownList Selecion in JS

Tags: javascript, .net

I am working on adding search panel. Here I have to populate the items based on the min and max price. My page front view is:

[image]

[image]

Here if I am selecting the min price value is 100,000 means max price must show the >=150,000 (It has to show only 150,000 & 200,000).

and if I'm selecting the min price value is 150,000 means max price must show the >=200,000 (It has to show only 200,000) etc.

How to do this function in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

When you select item from one dd you should detect items on next dd which do not match to corresponding condition.
I dont know what's your dd markup but in common way it should be something like this.

let `minDD` is your Min Price drop down and `maxDD` is Max Price drop down

```
//add event listeners
    for(var i=0;i<minDD.children.length;i++){
        $(minDD.children[i]).click(function(){
             setLimits(maxDD,this.innerHTML,'min');  
         })
    }
  for(var i=0;i<maxDD.children.length;i++){
         $(maxDD.children[i]).click(function(){
             setLimits(minDD,this.innerHTML,'max');  
         })
    }

//method removes unwanted items     

      function setLimits(node, val, indicator) {
            if (indicator == 'min') {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

                    if (node.childen[i].innerHTML < val)
                        node.removeChild(node.childen[i]);
                }
            }
            if (indicator == 'max') {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

                    if (node.childen[i].innerHTML > val)
                        node.removeChild(node.childen[i]);
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy paste this code it's just an example how you can do it, as I say above I don't know your drop-down markup